# How to display the APP on the Wall and News Feed

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-social-plugins

I created a Facebook APP which is being used for FB Connect Feature... everything is working fine.

But now I would like to display my APP on the Wall and News Feed, and also give the user the opportunity to share my APP.

How can I do this? I searched on Google and checked the Facebook API but couldn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Facebook Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)...
Here you will find methods to embed share and like buttons on your site.  When users interact with these social plugins, stories will be created on their feed and their friends will see this activity.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but i tought that i might have to create an Open Grpah for this... am i wrong?

Comment: You will need to embed into your page some `og:tags` for the plugins to be able to extract information about your page (title, image,etc...).  You can read here more about the [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Comment: That's exactly what i did yesterday, but it didn't seems being working... I checked on my Wall and News Feed but my Web page was not intergrated into the social graph. THX.